# getting error when trying to launch kotlin jar file that use supabase "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError"

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, desktop, supabase

when i try to launch the jar file that i build from my kotlin program on desktop in the intillij IDE it work perfectly but when i try to run it using JAR with the terminal it show me this error
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/github/jan/supabase/SupabaseClientBuilder
at org.main.MainKt.main(Main.kt:19)
at org.main.MainKt.main(Main.kt)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.github.jan.supabase.SupabaseClientBuilder
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:526)
... 2 more"
how can i fix it ?

i have checked all the implementation and gradle file file and asked ChatGPT but i found nothing